# I want to prevent line breaks when using Regex from matching

Tags: python-3.x, regex, text, nlp

I am using this regex pattern to extract VAT numbers from texts.

```
(?:(?:A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|P|Q|R|S|U|V|W|X|Y|Z){1}(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9_,\/°:]\s?\d{2}[^a-zA-Z0-9_,:]|[^a-zA-Z0-9_,\/°:]?\s?\d{2}[^a-zA-Z0-9_,\/:]?)(?:\d{3}[^a-zA-Z0-9_,\/-:]?\d{2}\w|\d{2}[^a-zA-Z0-9_,\/-:]?\d{2}[^a-zA-Z0-9_,\/.-:]?\d{2}|\d{5}\-[A-Z])|\d{8}[^a-zA-Z0-9_,\/-:]?[A-Z])\b
```

It works quite well in almost all scenarios, but I can't stop it from catching line breaks. As in the following text example:

```
BLABLABLABLA
C.I.F.B-95720122
ASISTENCIA: 610705956/695478047
BLABLABLABLA@hotmail.es
NO FACTURA.
20200901
DATOS DEL CLIENTE
BLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLA
B-95594896
DERIO
```

Where it returns:

```
B-95720122
```

```
A.
20200901
```

```
B-95594896
```

But only I want:

```
B-95720122
```

```
B-95594896
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Replace all of your `\s` with a single space and also `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\w`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I had a concept error with `\ s`

Answer (score 2):

\s will consider all white spaces. So the new line also will come under this. So, you have use normal space character instead \s.